How to deal with the problem that the path cannot be found during embedded configuration in CLion？
I tried to do the embedded development of stm32 on CLion, and there were many problems in the configuration process, mainly the header file path problem.
The compiler gives me following error when I tried to compile the main.c:
In file included from C:\Users\22918\CLionProjects\untitled\User\Src\main.c:1:
c:\users\22918\clionprojects\untitled\start\inc\stm32f10x.h:8300:12: fatal error: stm32f10x_conf.h: No such file or directory
 8300 |   #include "stm32f10x_conf.h"
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

here is the whole CMakeLists.txt:

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

# specify cross-compilers and tools
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-g++)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER  arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_AR arm-none-eabi-ar)
set(CMAKE_OBJCOPY arm-none-eabi-objcopy)
set(CMAKE_OBJDUMP arm-none-eabi-objdump)
set(SIZE arm-none-eabi-size)
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)

# project settings
project(untitled C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

#Uncomment for hardware floating point
#add_compile_definitions(ARM_MATH_CM4;ARM_MATH_MATRIX_CHECK;ARM_MATH_ROUNDING)
#add_compile_options(-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16)
#add_link_options(-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16)

#Uncomment for software floating point
#add_compile_options(-mfloat-abi=soft)

add_compile_options(-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -mthumb-interwork)
add_compile_options(-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-common -fmessage-length=0)

# uncomment to mitigate c++17 absolute addresses warnings
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-register")

# Enable assembler files preprocessing
add_compile_options($<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:ASM>:-x$<SEMICOLON>assembler-with-cpp>)

if ("${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "Release")
    message(STATUS "Maximum optimization for speed")
    add_compile_options(-Ofast)
elseif ("${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "RelWithDebInfo")
    message(STATUS "Maximum optimization for speed, debug info included")
    add_compile_options(-Ofast -g)
elseif ("${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" STREQUAL "MinSizeRel")
    message(STATUS "Maximum optimization for size")
    add_compile_options(-Os)
else ()
    message(STATUS "Minimal optimization, debug info included")
    add_compile_options(-Og -g)
endif ()

include_directories(Library/Inc Start/Inc System/Inc User/Inc)

add_definitions(-DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F103xB)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "startup/*.*" "Library/*.*" "Start/*.*" "System/*.*" "User/*.*")

set(LINKER_SCRIPT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/STM32F103C8Tx_FLASH.ld)

add_link_options(-Wl,-gc-sections,--print-memory-usage,-Map=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.map)
add_link_options(-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -mthumb-interwork)
add_link_options(-T ${LINKER_SCRIPT})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf ${SOURCES} ${LINKER_SCRIPT})

set(HEX_FILE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.hex)
set(BIN_FILE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.bin)

add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}.elf POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -Oihex $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}.elf> ${HEX_FILE}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -Obinary $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}.elf> ${BIN_FILE}
        COMMENT "Building ${HEX_FILE}
Building ${BIN_FILE}")

I followed the config course from:
https://www.bilibili.com/read/cv11442303/
IDE：CLion 2024.1
Toolchain: Arm-none-eabi-gcc
Chiptype：STM32F103C8Tx
I did finish the config on CMakeLists.txt to include the header files:
include_directories(Library/Inc Start/Inc System/Inc User/Inc)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "startup/*.*" "Library/*.*" "Start/*.*" "System/*.*" "User/*.*")


The compiler searches headers in the directories specified as include directories. I see the only include_directories call in your CMakeLists.txt. Does any of the directories you passed to it - Library/Inc, Start/Inc, System/Inc, User/Inc - contain the file stm32f10x_conf.h?

Yes, the file 'stm32f10x_conf.h' is contained in the "User" directory.

Is it contained directly in the User directory or in the User/Inc? What is the absolute path of file stm32f10x_conf.h?

Along with another header file, stm32f10x_it . h. Actually I put all of the Standard library function in Library/Inc,  Assemble program in startup.

in the User/Inc.

Actually, it is the relative path, I remember that the header file path Settings in CMakeLists . txt generally recommend using relative rather than absolute paths. Maybe I can try the absolute path later!

I had tried but it didn't work. don't understand this kind of magic bug.......
